# Imperfect or perfect fluid in Einstein Field Equation

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm trying to solve the Einstein Field Equations in an unconventional way (at least not usual from what is done in most basic textbooks). So basically, I specified a metric tensor (specifying a geometry) and I solve for the energy-momentum tensor that would result in this geometry.

Suppose I now have the result to be $T_{\mu\nu}$ to have the following non-zero terms:
\begin{align}
T_{00} & = \rho(r,t) \\
T_{11} & = p_{1}(r,t) \\
T_{22} & = p_{2}(r,t) \\
T_{33} & = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}p_{2}(r,t)
\end{align}
Can I call this an anisotropic fluid?

Comment: I think so. However the $\phi$-$\phi$ component, which represents the pressure in the azimuthal direction, becomes $\pm \infty$ along the polar axis. It is not an ordinary fluid.